# Building docker image for linux on windows server 2019 fails

Tags: windows-server-2019, docker-ee

We are building a .net 5.0 gRPC service and using the below command trying to create docker image for linux on my dev machine (windows 10 with Docker Desktop) works just fine:

docker build --platform=linux . -t repo:imagename --no-cache

the issue is that our CI/CD pipeline uses windows server 2019 and Docker desktop cannot be installed, so I followed this:

[Docker Linux Container running on Windows Server 2019](https://mountainss.wordpress.com/2020/03/31/docker-linux-container-running-on-windows-server-2019-winserv-docker-containers/)

and that seems to work to run linux images on the server but not to build them? Is this even possible?

docker version gives:

[image]

you can see that the OS/Arch is windows for the docker server and even using lcow cannot get it to be linux

so building gives the following error:

failed to get destination image "sha256:guid": image with reference sha256:guid was found but does not match the specified platform: wanted linux/amd64, actual: windows/amd64

Any help is appreciated